# Disabling horizontal split in Ace Editor

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I am using [Ace Editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about). As is shown in the page that I linked, the editor appears with an empty portion on the right side (which I believe is the split view) with a vertical line between it and the (main) editing space. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not a split view but a print margin - simple line at the specified column, to help seeing when lines become too long.

To disable it use

```
editor.setOption("showPrintMargin", false)
```

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me. Add the following piece of code and the line just vanishes off.

```
editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
```